# To Sleep() or not, and what is the proper way if Sleep() is bad?

Tags: .net, multithreading

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9417260/229930) SO question and noting the consensus about just how evil `Thread.Sleep()` in production code is, I decided to give an example of where I use it in production code and hopefully get an idea how to achieve what I'm currently using the `Thread.Sleep()` for in some other, better way...

Anyway, I have objects that are accessing a legacy system (IBM Terminal). Sometimes it can take even up to few seconds for a confirmation message to appear on the terminal screen or for screen navigation to finish. In my code I need to check if a certain system message appeared on the screen or if navigation finished by establishing that the terminal moved to the proper screen or that a certain system message was returned by the system. If the message is not on the screen or the screen has not changed I need to wait a few hundred miliseconds and try getting the confirmation string from the screen again and keep doing that either until the expected message is on the screen or the predefined operation timeout is reached.

The code looks something like this:

```
while (!SysOutput.Contains(successMsg) && 
OutputWaitCounter < WaitTime * Settings.Default.WaitTimeMultiplier)
{
    Thread.Sleep(Settings.Default.ThreadSleepTime);
    OutputWaitCounter++;
    DsGetAttributes = HostSession.GetAttributes(GetAttributes);
    SysOutput = DsGetAttributes.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
}
```

Please ignore the DataSet stuff, that is something from the 3rd party API I have to use...

Finally, the question is simple, is using `Thread.Sleep()` in this context in production code okay or not? If not, how would you resolve this problem of having to wait a few hundred miliseconds before attempting to get the system output from an IBM terminal?

Comment: Does your situation match the criteria I listed in my answer to the question that you linked?

Comment: @ChrisShain, I believe it does... what do you think?

Comment: I know nothing about IBM terminal, so I don't have enough information to determine whether it meets those criteria or not.  I also don't know if you tested vs. SpinWait() or even just calling `HostSession.GetAttributes` in a hot loop.

Comment: 3270-type terminals can make you wait quite a while for results a lot of time.  Using a hot loop or SpinWait() can be a great way to heat up your datacenter, 'cause you're gonna do a lot of waiting :)

Comment: How does SysOutput get updated?

Comment: @DaveMarkle Exactly, I see you're familiar with the pain...

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It is a function of the 3rd party .NET API I mentioned...

Comment: @DeanK: I did some work about 10 years ago integrating my C++ windows apps with Rumba on mainframes.  So yes, I got quite the taste of terminal emulation back in the day.  I know it hurts.  I think I used Sleep back then to do some of my waits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with Thread.Sleep() is that it stops *everything* on that thread.  I wouldn't say that you should *never* use it in production code -- it very much depends on what that code does and how it does it.

If this is some single-threaded command-line app that makes these calls, honestly, I don't see a big deal about it.  If it significantly simplifies your code in this case without side effects, I say leave it in.

If this is part of a larger application, say, with other threads and/or a rich UI, Sleep() can be problematic.  Let's say you want to signal this thread to stop immediately, presumably because someone is attempting to shut down the app (from another thread).  Instead of having to wait for your Sleep() call to finish, you'd probably want to use something like a Semaphore to signal to your thread that it's time to stop waiting, stop the thread, and clean up.  So in that case, you might instead wait on the semaphore to release (with a timeout).  If the call to waiting on the semaphore times out, you'd just proceed as normal, like you are doing now.  If the semaphore actually released, in this case, you'd then clean up your threads and exit gracefully.  Using Thread.Sleep() makes it so that your other threads would likely have to wait longer to exit in this case, because there would be no choice but to wait out the Sleep() call.  If you have a UI and you're Sleep()ing on your UI thread, calls to Sleep() will probably result in either a choppy or wholly unresponsive UI.

Comment: Simplest solution to the sleep() shutdown issue is to not clean up those threads that use it, just exit.

Comment: @Dave Markle It is a windows service and each object that interacts with the terminal is running on it's own thread...

Comment: @Martin James: That may be true, but aborting threads forcefully can do some really nasty things to your app when it comes to resource management, especially in this case.  Because he's working with a terminal emulator, I'd suspect he's probably doing some sort of COM interop with the terminal software, and not cleaning up those resources can lead to big nasty resource leaks which you really don't want!

Comment: @Dean K: If your Sleep() calls really are a 100-ish ms apiece, you could get away with this.  But if they can wait seconds, I'd think you could potentially run into some pain when stopping your apps from the service control manager.  If you want to do any communication with these threads, Sleep() can slow you down too.  Like I said, it's not really necessarily a dealbreaker for what you're doing.  If what you have works, and you like the performance of it, you aren't going to update it to be fancy in the future, I say leave it!

Comment: +1: I agree. Aside from calling it on a UI thread I don't see what the big deal is either. Sure, there's usually a better way, but it just depends on what you want to achieve.