# Global variable not being initilized in a new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, global

I have tried using volatile ....

q is a global class variable that should be able to be accessed by any members in the class.
would i have to create a 
Thread t; in class A ?

```
class A
{
    string q;
    public void SomeMethod ()
    { 
         new Thread(Method ()).Start();

         Console.WriteLine (q);   //this writes out nothing
    }
    private void Method ()
    { 
         q = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The main thread, the one that executes `Console.WriteLine(q)`, is running that line and exiting before the new thread that you started has a chance to set the variable's value.

Do some research on thread synchronization.

Comment: yup (: thanks. i just figured it out myself. i didn't think the thread start would take that long

Comment: @LawrenceL Please stop even thinking about relying on how long tasks take as being a viable synchronisation method.

Comment: @LawrenceL: Assume that starting a thread takes about a century, because that's how long it takes from the perspective of the CPU. You can expect a thread start to take at a minimum **hundreds of thousands of machine cycles**.  Threads are **incredibly expensive resources**. Think of a thread the way you'd think about hiring a new team member; it could take months, doing so is extremely expensive, and you'd better have work for them to do.

Comment: @EricLippert - firing them is expensive as well - they are all fully unionized.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (note this is so your brain grasps the reason your code does not work. It is NOT a suggestion for a pattern to use - thanks for the comment Chris):

```
class A 
{ 
  string q; 
  public void SomeMethod () 
  {  
    new Thread(Method ()).Start(); 
    //Add this so the thread finishes (not a good permanent solution)
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Console.WriteLine (q);   //this writes out nothing 
  } 
  private void Method () 
  {  
    q = "Hello World"; 
  } 
}
```

Why is this going to work? Because it gives the first thread a chance to finish its work before you write to console. What this means is one thread is writing while the other is setting.

Now, a better way is lock the variable when changing/retrieving q. A simple lock would be fine in this example. Just lock the variable both when you set and when you retrieve to write to console.

Comment: See the ongoing SO topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417260/when-is-it-sensible-to-use-thread-sleep

Comment: @Chris Slain: It was for demo purposes only, which is why I stuck the comment. I guess I should have been more clear (editing now)

Comment: @GregoryABeamer: lock will *not* help to solve the OP' original problem: most likely the main thread will terminate earlier than `Method()` has a chance to start.

Comment: You might know that Sleep is a bad idea, but even mentioning it like this is just misleading to an obvious novice with threads. I consider this answer worthy of downvotes.

Answer (score -1):

You're not blocking execution to wait for your new thread to execute. If you just want to make it write something out, you can use a waitHandle or a really simple boolean flag like this:

```
class A 
{ 
string q; 
bool hasBeenSet;
public void SomeMethod () 
{  
     new Thread(Method ()).Start(); 

     while(!hasBeenSet)
     {
       Thread.Sleep(10);
     }

     Console.WriteLine (q);   //this writes out nothing 
} 
private void Method () 
{  
     q = "Hello World"; 
     hasBeenSet = true;
} 
}
```

Although that being said, you should really do some research on WaitHandles and synchronization objects/ patterns.

Comment: Why do a busywait over a simple join?