# How to block an operation until a condition is met?

Tags: c#, blocking

I am running this code and it is using a fair amount of CPU even though it is doing absolutely nothing most of the time.

```
while (this.IsListening)
{
    while (this.RecievedMessageBuffer.Count > 0)
    {
        lock (this.RecievedMessageBuffer)
        {
            this.RecievedMessageBuffer[0].Reconstruct();
            this.RecievedMessageBuffer[0].HandleMessage(messageHandler);
            this.RecievedMessageBuffer.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to block until a condition is met?

Comment: Thread.Sleep() blocks the UI as well.

Comment: @RanhiruCooray no, that's almost always the *wrong* answer.  There are structures dedicated to this job, like the WaitHandle suggested by Mark.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417260/when-is-it-sensible-to-use-thread-sleep

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using .NET 4, I'd suggest switching `RecievedMessageBuffer` to be a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).  When you are putting messages into it, call it's [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287137.aspx) method.  When you want to retrieve a message, call it's [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085.aspx) or [TryTake](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287154.aspx) methods.  Take will block the reading thread until a message is available, without burning CPU like your original example.

```
// Somewhere else
BlockingCollection<SomethingLikeAMessage> RecievedMessageBuffer = new BlockingCollection<SomethingLikeAMessage>();


// Something like this where your example was
while (this.IsListening)
{
    SomethingLikeAMessage message;
    if (RecievedMessageBuffer.TryTake(out message, 5000);
    {
        message.Reconstruct();
        message.HandleMessage(messageHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! that is perfect for what I needed! I was using a SyncronizedCollection<> before but as BlockingCollection<> is also thread safe, this is perfect for what I am doing! Everything is running fantastically smooth now!

Answer (score 11):

Use a `WaitHandle`.

```
WaitHandle waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent();

// In your thread.
waitHandle.WaitOne();

// In another thread signal that the condition is met.
waitHandle.Set();
```

You could also consider changing the interface of your class to raise an event when there is new data to be read. Then you can put your code inside the event handler.

Comment: I'll have to do some testing with WaitHandles. Never knew about them before today. Never did anything too serious with multithreading before a few weeks ago.

Comment: I couldn't use `WaitHandle` with `Set()` method. I think there should be at least `EventWaitHandle` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Above lines of code and specifically AutoResetEvent is available in version 3.5. So simple code like above with some minor correction is very effective because it works and close to foundation API. The correction should be

AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false); 
Constructor with argument false makes WaitOne() to wait because AutoResetEven is not reset (false). There is not much advantage of using interface WaitHandle, so I would just use AutoResetEvent instead as it exposes method Set and WaitOne is quite verbose in this case. Most importantly, the constructor argument and should be false.